# JFrame + JDialog's to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, cardlayout

I have a game. Menu via `JFrame`, game via `JDialog`, but I want to create one frame (1280x1024) and have all my menus, pop-ups and game be in one window.

Is it possible?

Comment: See this answer to [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) for lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure ! Take a look to JMenuBar and JInternalFrame :)